# Terminal closes after using a bash file

Tags: command-line, bash, libreoffice

So I'm currently in internship and we work here with mintlinux.

My boss wants me to create an executable file that automatically updates libreoffice from 5.1 to 5.3 after clicking on it.

I created the bash file like this (I'm not sure if this is even correct, since I don't use mintlinux or have any expierence with it)

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But the terminal closes in an instant after I open the bash file, any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Try with a terminal window, that is already open, and start the command by entering the command line `bash name-of-the-shellscript-file` (with the actual name of the file).

Comment: "mintlinux" questions are off-topic here but try http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wish for the window to stay up until you can see what kind of output you have there, you can use the read -command.

```
read -rsp $'Press enter to continue...\n'
```

But I sense there is a bigger problem there: it is rarely a good idea to use "sudo" in bash scripts. Instead you should *run* the script *with* a sudo command instead.

And your script, it doesn't simply update Libre Office, it does a complete system updgrade for **all** packages.

If you wish to update Libre Office *only*, then you need to specify that:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libreoffice
```

If your boss wishes the Libre Office installations stay up to date, you might wish to check how to do this with cron; if can help you do it at each reboot, every X hours (or minutes), etc.

And since there is a crontab for "root"(ie. run: "sudo crontab -e"), you'd have no "sudo problems" either if you handle it that way.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an executable file from the graphical interface, it executes the content of it from beginning to end, and at the end it exits.

If you want to keep the terminal open for some reason (i.e. checkin the output), after the script finishes, you can for example:

- Execute the script from a terminal using: `./your_script.sh`
- Add an ´sleep´ at the end. This way the script will execute from beginning to end, but it won't reach the end until the "sleeping time" is over. You can do it like this:

List item

```
 #! /bin/bash

 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa 
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

 sleep 30
```

This will keep your terminal open for 30 seconds after the apt-get command is finished (or crashed).
You can use other time values (units), such as "5m" (5 minutes) or "2h" (2 hours).